# Environment variable in spring boot application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new in Spring Boot. Trying a set my database credentials in environment variable using

```
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=scott

export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=tiger
```

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/SID
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

getting invalid username/password error.

Comment: Sorry. Its a typo. Updated.

Comment: This should work. What is your Spring Boot version and what is the ORA code that is thrown in exception.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

username:  ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

mushariar@L-MAC-19 spring-project % echo $SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME           
scott
hasan.ahmmed@L-MAC-19 spring-project % echo $SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD           
tiger

If I write hard coded values in yml file it works everything as expected.

Comment: How are you starting the application? Is it from IDE (IntelliJ?) or from command line (Gradle or java -jar)?

Comment: IDE IntelliJ. Run or debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the environment variables in the shell using `export` directive however you are running the application from within IntelliJ IDEA.

If you use IntelliJ to start the application you should set the environment variable directly in the IntelliJ runtime configuration, as shown on picture below:

[image]

You could add your exports to `.profile` (or `.bashrc`) file but this would force you to restart IntelliJ each time this file is modified.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot